# Importing a class in Laravel 5.5

Tags: php, forms, laravel, request

I'm trying to include the class that treats the Request from my form, but it always returns error from not found, however, I've already checked and reverted and the file and patch are correct.

I already tried to update the composer to see if it solved, but without success, follow the code below.

> Arguments "Class App\Http\Requests\CadastroRequest does not exist"

File CadastroController.php

```html
<?

    namespace App\Http\Controllers;

    use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB; // Banco de dados
    use Request; // Tratamento URI
    use Validator; // Validação
    use App\Cadastro; // Modelo
    use App\Http\Requests\CadastroRequest; // Regras do formulário

    class CadastroController extends Controller {

        // Formulário de Cadastro
        public function cadastro(){

            return view('cadastro.formulario');

        }

        // Registrar Usuário
        public function salvar( CadastroRequest $request ){

            Cadastro::create( $request->all() );
            return redirect('/cadastro/obrigado')->withInput();

        }

    }
?>
```

File CadastroRequest.php (root/app/Http/Requests/CadastroRequest.php)

```html
<?php

    namespace App\Http\Requests;

    use Illuminate\Foundation\Http\FormRequest;

    class CadastroRequest extends FormRequest { 

        public function authorize() {
            return true; // Manter true para teste
        }

        public function rules() {
            return [
                # Informações de contato
                'nome' => 'required|min:10',
                'email' => 'required|min:10',
                'celular' => 'min:11|max:15',
                # Informações de acesso
                'senha' => 'required|numeric|min:3|max:8',
                'rsenha' => 'required|numeric|min:3|max:8',
                # Informações de endereço
                'estado' => 'required|min:10',
                'cidade' => 'required|min:10',
                'cep' => 'required|min:10',
                'endereco' => 'required|min:10',
                'numero' => 'required|min:10',
                'bairro' => 'required|min:10',

            ];
        }

        public function messages(){

            return [
                'nome.required' => 'Você precisa informar seu nome.'
                'email.required' => 'Insira um e-mail valido, você precisa confirmar o registro.'
                'senha.required' => 'Senha é obrigatória.'
                'rsenha.required' => 'Confirmação da senha é obrigatória.'
                'estado.required' => 'Saber seu estado ajuda a lhe informar jogos acontecendo no seu estado.'
                'cidade.required' => 'Saber a cidade que mora ajuda a lhe informar os jogos próximos a você.'
                'cep.required' => 'Campo CEP é obrigatório.'
                'endereco.required' => 'Campo Endereço é obrigatório.'
                'numero.required' => 'Campo Número é obrigatório.'
                'bairro.required' => 'Campo Bairro é obrigatório.'
            ];

        }
    }
```

Comment: Have you tried `php artisan cache:clear` and `composer dumpautoload`?

Comment: Did not work, any other suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Run this in your terminal :

`composer dump-autoload`

it will add your class to your project

If it not work, try to add the new request via artisan :

`php artisan make:request CadastroRequest`

then just copy and paste your code

Comment: Edit to add another solution

Comment: I found the problem, it was actually stupid. A comma was missing from the array. However, I found this a failure of Laravel, for comma error for example he says he did not find the class and not that there is an error in the syntax.